# Newton - Unexpected token while deserializing object

Tags: c#, arrays, json

Unexpected token while deserializing object: PropertyName. Path 'Shipments[0].ShipmentItems', line 24, position 28.

Hoping someone can assist or guide me on why I'm encountering this error when attempting to deserialize the object. Despite validating that the JSON returned from the restAPI is correctly formatted and valid, the error persists. Not entirely sure what I am doing wrong here or missing, any help would be greatly appreciated.

snip of the code part
How it's being deserialized

```
string json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    RootObject root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);
```

Json part

```
 {
  "shipments": [
    {
      "shipmentId": 123456789,
      "orderNumber": "900678-Z",
      "createDate": "2023-04-03T06:51:33.6270000",
      "shipDate": "2023-04-10",
      "trackingNumber": "NONE",
      "shipTo": {
    "name": "John D",
    "company": "",
    "street1": "12223 MAIN STREET",
    "street2": "",
    "street3": null,
    "city": "DALLAS",
    "state": "TX",
    "postalCode": "12345-1111",
    "country": "US",
    "phone": "000-000-0000",
    "residential": null
  },
  "advancedOptions": null,
  "ShipmentItems": [
    {
      "orderItemId": 56789403,
      "lineItemKey": null,
      "sku": "PDOLSQ3785739",
      "name": "Potato Kitten -",
      "imageUrl": null,
      "weight": null,
      "quantity": 1,
      "unitPrice": 1,
      "warehouseLocation": null,
      "options": null,
      "productId": 1065998,
      "fulfillmentSku": null
    }
  ],
  "labelData": null,
  "formData": null
   }
  ],
  "total": 1,
  "page": 1,
  "pages": 0
}
```

Class model

```
 public partial class RootObject
{
    [JsonProperty("shipments")]
    public List<Shipment> Shipments { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("total")]
    public int Total { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("page")]
    public int Page { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("pages")]
    public int Pages { get; set; }
}

public partial class Shipment
{
    [JsonProperty("shipmentId")]
    public long ShipmentId { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("orderNumber")]
    public string OrderNumber { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("createDate")]
    public DateTimeOffset CreateDate { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("shipDate")]
    public DateTimeOffset ShipDate { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("trackingNumber")]
    public string TrackingNumber { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("shipTo")]
    public ShipTo ShipTo { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("advancedOptions")]
    public object AdvancedOptions { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("shipmentItems")]
    public List<ShipmentItem> ShipmentItems { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("labelData")]
    public object LabelData { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("formData")]
    public object FormData { get; set; }
}

public partial class ShipTo
{
    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("company")]
    public string Company { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("street1")]
    public string Street1 { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("street2")]
    public string Street2 { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("street3")]
    public object Street3 { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("city")]
    public string City { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("state")]
    public string State { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("postalCode")]
    public string PostalCode { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("country")]
    public string Country { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("phone")]
    public string Phone { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("residential")]
    public bool Residential { get; set; }
}

public partial class ShipmentItem
{
    [JsonProperty("orderItemId")]
    public long OrderItemId { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("lineItemKey")]
    public string LineItemKey { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("sku")]
    public string Sku { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("imageUrl")]
    public uri ImageUrl { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("weight")]
    public double Weight { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("quantity")]
    public in Quantity { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("unitPrice")]
    public double UnitPrice { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("warehouseLocation")]
    public string WarehouseLocation { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("options")]
    public string Options { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("productId")]
    public long ProductId { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("fulfillmentSku")]
    public string FulfillmentSku { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to change these properties to nullable, since they have null value in a json string. And maybe it makes some sense to review another not nullable properties too, if they can be null in a json string

```
     [JsonProperty("residential")]
      public bool? Residential { get; set; }

        .....

    [JsonProperty("weight")]
     public double? Weight { get; set; }
```